# How can I get the class name from a function pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, function-pointers

I have a base class "TestBase"

Several test classes inherit from it and override the "Test" function of the base class.

The TestBase class uses a 'TestRunner' class and passes it a pointer to it's 'Test' function (which is overridden).

Inside 'TestRunner' a timeout may occur.  If this happens, I need to know the name of the derived class that the 'Test' pointer belongs to.

All I have is the function pointer.  So basically, I want to know the name of the derived class that the 'Test' function pointer came from.

I'm guessing Reflection can do this, but I'm having trouble finding out how..

To clarify, the function pointer 'test' is defined as:

```
Func<bool> test
```

Passed in as follows:

```
public void RunTest(Func<bool> test, int timeoutInSeconds=30)
{
   ...
   //Use 'test' to find out what class it came from...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is a "pointer to it's 'Test' function" in C# ?

Comment: Probably a Func<> or Action<> I assume

Comment: Yes.  'test' is   Func<bool> test